# ViewGroup (LinearLayout) and Child onClick event not passed to ViewGroup

Tags: android, onclick, viewgroup

I have a `LinearLayout` with several seekbars as childs, on the `SeekBars` i use the `android:clickable=false` and on the LinearLayout i have the `android:clickable=true`and the corresponding `setOnClickListenner` defined however any press on the the `SeekBars` doesn't trigger the `LinearLayout` click, i have read somewhere that it should and tested it by replacing the `SeekBars` with `Buttons` and setting the `clickable` property to `false` and the click is bubbled up to the parent.
My question is why the behaviour is not similar ?

Edit: Added code example

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SeekBar

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me!"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Container was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });




}
}
```

Comment: Well you are missing this in your code: "and on the LinearLayout i have the `android:clickable=true`"

Comment: Yes what i posted is an example by using the setOnClickListener its irrelevant the behaviour is the same even with or without `android:clickable=true` on clicking the `LinearLayout` the listener is invoked on clicking the SeekBar it is not the and on cliking the Button the event is invoked.

Comment: okay, so when you click the button it DOES work? and when you click the seekbar it does NOT work? correct?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener`

Comment: Im using an inner anonymous class as usual `new View.OnClickListener()` so it it isn't required

Comment: having re-read you question several times, I finally think I understand your question. "Why does it work when you click the button, but not work when you click the seekBar"

Comment: Yes thats exactly my question

Answer (score 0):

Having finally understood what you are asking I think this will fix it. The `SeekBar` is not focusable and the `Button` is.

This is the reason it will not work for you delete this line from the `SeekBar`:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Allowing this to be focusable should make both the `Button` and `SeekBar` function the same way when they are clicked.

Comment: I probably asked the question in a confused way or you misunderstood i know that setting `clickable`to `false` makes the program ignore the clicks thats what i want to happen on the SeekBar i wan't that uppon clicking on it the event is bubbled up to the parent (the `LinearLayout`) which has a click event defined.